# Grid items from a list in pairs tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I am trying to create a grid of 14 radiobuttons from a list of 14 items, I would like the buttons to be arranged in 7 pairs, so far, what I am getting is this with the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
bs = ['Skin and Soft Tissue', 'Bone and Joint', 'Central Nervous System', 'Genito- 
Urinary', 'Gastrointestinal', 'Cardiovascular', 'ENT', 'Gynaecological Infections', 
'Intravascular access Device', 'Sexual Transmitted Infections', 'Pregancy Associated 
Sepsis', 'Respiratory', 'Lyme Disease', 'Splenectomy/Functional Asplenia']
n = tk.StringVar()
nrows = 7
ncols = 2
nitems = 14
for r in range(nrows):
  for c in range(ncols):
    for body in range(len(bs)):
        tk.Radiobutton(root, text = bs[r], var = n, value = bs[r]).grid(row = 
        r, column = c)
root.mainloop()
```

What I am getting so far is this

[image]

**My question is, how do I get python to iterate every item on the list so I get all radiobuttons in 7 pairs all with their respective names?**

Comment: what are the suppposed pairs? I just see a one dimensional list that doesn't help understanding what you mean by pairs, if you need pairs, then group them together or use a dictionary or are they not related and you just want to spread the info across 2 columns?

Comment: Hi, they I don't think I cannot use a dictionary because I want each radiobuttoon to trigger a different thing.
The only reason I'd like them in pairs is because it looks far tidier.
I am ware I can create 2 different lists with 7 items each and run a for loop assigning a column to each list.

Comment: my question was if you actually had pairs of values that had to be on the same line or just for tidiness, you are fine with one list too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to position items in set rows and columns:

```py
import tkinter as tk

bs = ['Skin and Soft Tissue', 'Bone and Joint', 'Central Nervous System',
      'Genito-Urinary', 'Gastrointestinal', 'Cardiovascular', 'ENT',
      'Gynaecological Infections','Intravascular access Device',
      'Sexual Transmitted Infections', 'Pregancy Associated Sepsis',
      'Respiratory', 'Lyme Disease', 'Splenectomy/Functional Asplenia']


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')

n_rows = 7
n_cols = 2

n = tk.StringVar(value=' ')
for index, text in enumerate(bs):
    c = index // n_rows
    if c + 1 > n_cols:
        break
    tk.Radiobutton(
        root, text=text, var=n, value=text
    ).grid(row=index % n_rows, column=c, sticky='w')

root.mainloop()
```

First note that this loop prioritizes rows i.e. it first fills all the rows before going to the next column and also if there are more items than `n_cols * n_rows` it will break after it has filled all set rows and columns.

Basically it uses index to detect the item index and the `%` (modulo) to set the row since it calculates the reminder then for example 6th index will return 6 (7th row in order) and for 13th index (last item in this case) it will also return 6 (which again is 7th row in order) because that is the remainder when dividing 13 / 7 and that is what modulo returns. The column is simply set from the index ground divided by columns so basically it increases when the column is filled up since for example 7th index (8th item in list) will do `c = 7 // 7` which is 1 (2nd column) and then 13 // 7 is also 1 and so on. (also I would suggest using `sticky='w'` so that the checkbuttons are aligned on the left side (or whichever side you need))

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for r in range(nrows):
    for c in range(ncols):
        tk.Radiobutton(root, text = bs[r*ncols+c], var = n, value = bs[r*ncols+c]).grid(row = r, column = c)
```

it uses the formula `r*ncols+c` to find the appropriate item in the `bs` list.  If this is not intuitive then do some calculations to test it, eg

```
r   c   r*2+c
0   0       0
0   1       1
1   0       2
1   1       3
2   0       4
2   1       5
```

so far what I get is this:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcLag.png)

Comment: I am afraid it does not work, it does iterate through the items, but it duplicates the second item on each row on the following row

Comment: @Lord_Amengg  try `print(bs[r*ncols+c])` after the `tk.Radiobutton....` line.  Does it prints all items in in the list?

Comment: every item on the list gets printed 14 times:

Comment: Did you remove the `for body in range... ` line?

Comment: Now I did not, and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to grid items in pairs, inspired on the answer by Matiss that uses the modulo operator:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


bs = ['Skin and Soft Tissue', 'Bone and Joint', 'Central Nervous System', 'Genito-Urinary', 'Gastrointestinal', 'Cardiovascular', 'ENT', 'Gynaecological Infections','Intravascular access Device', 'Sexual Transmitted Infections', 'Pregancy Associated Sepsis', 'Respiratory', 'Lyme Disease', 'Splenectomy/Functional Asplenia']

 root = tk.Tk()
 root.geometry('600x600')
 n = tk.StringVar()
 for i in range(len(bs)):
 if i%2 == 0:
   tk.Radiobutton(root, text = bs[i], var = n, value = bs[i]).grid(row = i, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
else:
   tk.Radiobutton(root, text = bs[i], var = n, value = bs[i]).grid(row = i - 1, column = 1, sticky = 'nsew')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Many errors in this code

Comment: code amended, thanks for pointing it out.